# 'An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command' with capifony

Tags: symfony, capifony

I am trying to deploy with capifony, but when I run

```
$ cap deploy
```

It returns an error

```
--> Updating code base with remote_cache strategy
Password: 
--> Creating cache directory................................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared directories................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared files......................✔
--> Normalizing asset timestamps............................✔
--> Updating Composer.......................................✔
--> Updating Composer dependencies..........................✘
*** [err :: som.info] 
*** [err :: som.info] [RuntimeException]
*** [err :: som.info] An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.

*** [err :: som.info] Exception trace:
*** [err :: som.info] () at /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:182
*** [err :: som.info] Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::executeCommand() at /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Composer/ScriptHandler.php:62

.....
```

This is my **deploy.rb**

```
set :application, "sommelier"
set :domain,      "som.info"
set :deploy_to,   "/home/yamaken/#{domain}"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "git@github.com:haji/sommelier.git"
set :scm,         :git

set :default_shell,         "TERM=dumb sudo -u yamaken /bin/sh"

set :branch, "master"

set :scm_username, "haji"
set :scm_passphrase, "********"

set   :use_sudo,      false

set :user, 'yamaken'

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain, :primary => true       # This may be the same as your `Web` server

set  :keep_releases,  3
set :shared_files,        ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/spool",app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads","vendor"]


set :writable_dirs,       ["app/cache", "app/logs","app/spool"]
set :permission_method,   :chown #
set :use_set_permissions, false
```

I have tried the code according to @nifr suggestion.

```
$ _DEBUG=1 cap deploy
Ruby Version                      => 1.8.7-p358
OpenSSL::Version                  => OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
Net::SSH::Version::CURRENT        => 2.6.8
Net::SSH -> Local platform        => unix
Password: 
Remote Whoami                     => yamaken
umask on Server                   => 0022
$SHELL                            => /bin/bash
$BASH_VERSION                     => 4.1.5(1)-release
Interactive Shell - Test: $PS1    => no
  * 2013-12-04 11:45:36 executing `deploy'
  * 2013-12-04 11:45:36 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2013-12-04 11:45:36 executing `deploy:update_code'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
--> Updating code base with checkout strategy
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:haji/sommelier.git master"
    command finished in 2798ms
  * executing "git clone -q -b master git@github.com:haji/sommelier.git /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539 && cd /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539 && git checkout -q -b deploy 1ab8525ef883da0826b6b3d08a1c98da1904edd2 && (echo 1ab8525ef883da0826b6b3d08a1c98da1904edd2 > /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/REVISION)"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 24263ms
  * 2013-12-04 11:46:03 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 556ms
--> Creating cache directory
  * executing "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/cache ] ; then rm -rf /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/cache; fi'"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 374ms
  * executing "sh -c 'mkdir -p /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/cache && chmod -R 0777 /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/cache'"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 383ms
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/cache"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 365ms
  * 2013-12-04 11:46:05 executing `deploy:share_childs'
--> Creating symlinks for shared directories
  * executing "mkdir -p /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/app/spool"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 370ms
  * executing "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/spool ] ; then rm -rf /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/spool; fi'"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 373ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/app/spool /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/spool"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 372ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/app/logs"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 369ms
  * executing "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/logs ] ; then rm -rf /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/logs; fi'"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 366ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/app/logs /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/logs"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 376ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/web/uploads"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 373ms
  * executing "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/web/uploads ] ; then rm -rf /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/web/uploads; fi'"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 401ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/web/uploads /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/web/uploads"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 375ms
  * executing "mkdir -p /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/vendor"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 375ms
  * executing "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/vendor ] ; then rm -rf /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/vendor; fi'"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 969ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/vendor /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/vendor"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 366ms
--> Creating symlinks for shared files
  * executing "mkdir -p /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/app/config"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 366ms
  * executing "touch /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/app/config/parameters.yml"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 378ms
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/yamaken/som.info/shared/app/config/parameters.yml /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/app/config/parameters.yml"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 393ms
--> Normalizing asset timestamps
  * executing "find /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/web/css /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/web/images /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539/web/js -exec touch -t 201312040246.11 {} ';' &> /dev/null || true"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 383ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2013-12-04 11:46:12 executing `symfony:cache:warmup'
--> Warming up cache
  * executing "sh -c 'cd /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539 && php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug'"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 530ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539; true"
    servers: ["som.info"]
    [som.info] executing command
    command finished in 536ms
failed: "TERM=dumb sudo -u yamaken /bin/sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539 && php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug'\\'''" on som.info
```

I have another quesion, there is the way for not doing the line below after deploy fails?

```
executing "rm -rf /home/yamaken/som.info/releases/20131204024539; true"
```

If I can remain the fils on the server. I can check the cause by manual operation.

Comment: What happens if you run manually `php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup`?

Comment: cap deploy first try always fails,so there is no console file under app directory..,so it says 'Could not open input file: app/console'

Comment: and ,At the local, this command works well.

Comment: So, there you are? This exception is [thrown](http://bit.ly/1bfmI97) when the process returns a bad status code. If it didn't find the `app/console` file, that may be why it throws this exception.

Comment: I have another project,which I can deploy,however there is no console file neither and I can't do 'php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup'...

Comment: Please use the code in my answer to create a more verbose output and add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question :) only the relevant parts are needed beginning with the command that fails until "rolling back".

Comment: Now you have two different errors here ... the one on top of your question says `cache:clear --no-warmup` failed ... while the log you posted says `php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug` failed. can you please explain the difference?

Comment: On the server,the enviroment is automatically switched to 'prod' when you deploy.so I think these two are the same ,in the first box it says  'cache:clear --no-warmup' ,it is just the abbreviation of words.

Comment: I have another question,but it is different from this question,so I made another topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431038/how-to-not-delete-files-after-deployment-fails-by-capifony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debugging Capistrano deployments:**

A little trick i came up with to ease debugging is to use an environment variable to switch verbose output and some extra information on and off.

You can add something like this to your `deploy.rb` (extend or shorten if you like)...

```
unless ENV['_DEBUG'].nil?
    puts "Ruby Version                      => #{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"
    puts "OpenSSL::Version                  => #{OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION}"
    puts "Net::SSH::Version::CURRENT        => #{Net::SSH::Version::CURRENT}"
    puts "Net::SSH -> Local platform        => #{Net::SSH::Authentication::PLATFORM}"
    puts "Remote Whoami                     => #{capture 'whoami'}"
    puts "umask on Server                   => #{capture 'umask'}"
    puts "$SHELL                            => #{capture 'echo $SHELL'}"
    puts "$BASH_VERSION                     => #{capture 'echo $BASH_VERSION'}"
    puts "Interactive Shell - Test: $PS1    => #{capture 'if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then echo no; else echo yes; fi'}"

    logger.level =          Logger::MAX_LEVEL
    ssh_options[:verbose] = :debug 
end
```

Now execute:

```
_DEBUG=1 cap deploy
```

Comment: I have added comment to my post. I really appriciate your help

Comment: Thanks I close the project and make another project from the scratch.

Comment: then it works,however your reply is helpful. When I will bump into another problem.thanks